# In Revit API I am failing to transform a Sweep Profile Sketch to an XY in the same location relative to the Sweep Path

Tags: c#, path, profile, revit-api

Here is the below code that takes a Sweep(no symbol profiles are used) from a Revit project and then recycles the Sweep Profile instance and the Sweep Profile Path. I have another method not posted here to create the sweep in a family document. The issue is that the sweep usually is correctly formed however the XY position of the Sweep Profile after the transform to an XY plane is not in the same place relative to the Sweep Path as it was in the project document so sometimes the sweep forms ok in very simple cases like no bends and when the sweep is at 0,0,0 other times the Profile is so far from the path that the sweep is malformed. These are the arguments.....Document doc, Curve Array Array curve Array Array Profile, XYZ origin, XYZ normal, XYZ path Start

```
        private static CurveArrArray CreateTransformedProfile(Document doc, CurveArrArray curveArrArrayProfile, XYZ origin, XYZ normal, XYZ pathStart)
        {
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "Create Transformed Profile"))
            {
                t.Start();

                Transform transform1 = GetTransformToZ(normal, origin);
                Transform transform2 = Transform.CreateRotation(normal, 1.5 * Math.PI);
                Transform transform = transform1.Multiply(transform2);

                CurveArrArray transformedProfile = new CurveArrArray();

                foreach (CurveArray curveArray in curveArrArrayProfile)
                {
                    CurveArray transformedCurveArray = new CurveArray();
                    foreach (Curve curve in curveArray)
                    {
                        transformedCurveArray.Append(curve.CreateTransformed(transform));
                    }
                    transformedProfile.Append(transformedCurveArray);
                }


                XYZ profileCentre = CalculateProfileCentre(transformedProfile);
                double distance = pathStart.DistanceTo(profileCentre);

                //Testing Only@! 
                ConvertMIPFamilySolids.LinePathToCentre = Line.CreateBound(pathStart, profileCentre);
                XYZ vector = new XYZ(1, 1, 0);
                XYZ pathEnd = profileCentre.Add(vector);
                ConvertMIPFamilySolids.LinePathToEnd = Line.CreateBound(profileCentre, pathEnd);

                Transform translationToPathStart = Transform.CreateTranslation(pathStart - profileCentre);

                CurveArrArray finalProfile = new CurveArrArray();
                foreach (CurveArray curveArray in transformedProfile)
                {
                    CurveArray finalCurveArray = new CurveArray();
                    foreach (Curve curve in curveArray)
                    {
                        finalCurveArray.Append(curve.CreateTransformed(translationToPathStart));
                    }
                    finalProfile.Append(finalCurveArray);
                }

                t.Commit();

                return finalProfile;
            }
        }

        private static Transform GetTransformToZ(XYZ normal, XYZ origin)
        {
            Transform transform;

            double angle = XYZ.BasisZ.AngleTo(normal);

            if (IsZero(angle))
            {
                transform = Transform.Identity;
            }
            else
            {
                XYZ axis = IsEqual(angle, Math.PI) ? XYZ.BasisX : normal.CrossProduct(XYZ.BasisZ);
                transform = Transform.CreateRotationAtPoint(axis, angle, origin);
            }
            return transform;
        }
        private static bool IsZero(double value)
        {
            return Math.Abs(value) < 1e-6;
        }
        private static bool IsEqual(double value1, double value2)
        {
            return IsZero(value1 - value2);
        }
```

I have asked this question on the Revit API forums and I have received no answer. I might try a workaround and get the XYX rel1tive position in the Project Document and try to recreate in the family document the same offset. However I am thinking something I am doing in the transform of the profile using the plane XYZ to XY transform is offsetting the rotation is flawed and should try to resolve that first. Note an attempt I made in the last method to get the path center to move the profile. Also the second transform works and is a flat rotation in the XY plane, it does not seem to affect the outcome too much so I do not think that is the source of the issue as it was still not right before I introduced transform B.

Comment: I not sure I understand your situation correctly. Could you provide some images to visualize how it is and how it supposes to be? Furthermore, I don't understand if "normal " and "origin" are the current values or the desired values? It is even better if you could update your question on Revit API forum and share us a link .